# Expected value | Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

expected value

If $E(X)=0$, then $X=0$.

I know it's false, but how do I argue it?

Comment: To argue against a claim, you have to provide an _explicit_ example where the claim DOES NOT HOLD (i.e. provide $X$ such that $X$ is simultaneously not zero and $E(X) = 0.$) To construct $X$, think of it as having equal mass to the right and left of zero so they cancell out! (But be aware that you have to explicitly construct $X.$)

Answer (score 6):

You can create an example of random variable that's its expected value is zero, but this variable can get no-zero values.

for example: consider the variable $X$ that gets the value of $1$ in probability $0.5$ and gets the value $-1$ in probability $0.5$

In a more general way, an expected value behaves somewhat similar to average, as you maybe know, average of values can be for example $M$, when none of the values is $M$ (although that for your question it is enough that just **one** of the values is not $M$)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your query. I would suggest you try this example: let $U$ be the random variable that takes the values $\{-n, -n+1, \cdots, 0, 1, \cdots, n\}$ (each with probability $\frac{1}{2n+1}$). Could you please try to find the expected value of $U$? Can you construct a continuous random variable $R$ which has $E(R)=0$? We assume $R$ the non-zero random variable. Thanks to the user e.ad, I agree my example is similar to his (or hers).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you implicitely have the further hypothesis that $X≥0.$ In this case the statement

"$E(X)=0$ implies $Pr(X=0)=1$"

deserves indeed a little proof. Suppose that $E(X)=0$ and that there exists a number $a$ small enough such that $Pr(X>a)=p>0.$ As a consequence since

$$X\geq X1_{X>a}\Rightarrow 0=E(X)\geq E(X1_{X>a})\geq aE(1_{X>a})=ap>0$$ we get the desired contradiction.